# How do you format a number into a string with padded zeros?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, formatting

Very simply in SQL Server T-SQL parlance, how do you conver the number 9 to the string N'00009'?

Comment: Typically, you would let your UI do this job...

Comment: Typically, I would let my middle tier do this job not my UI, but in this case, that wouldn't work, which is why I am asking the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CAST(number AS NVARCHAR), 5)
```

The result will be a string, not a number type.

Comment: I'm not sure, does that work if the number is `143`? Would `00143` be returned or `00000143`? @Jordan: Google-search for "Sql Server padding function" to see implementations of `lpad` and `rpad`. Seems the usually use `replicate` and `len`.

Comment: @Frustrated - No it only takes the 5 rightmost chars after the concatenation.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, Yes, it will work for 143 and any number up to 99999.  I chose the 5-digit presentation because I saw that format in the question.  The replicate and len will work as well.

Comment: Yup. Works. Brilliant. That is all.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on SQL Server 2012 or later, you can also use the [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(1, '00000') AS PaddedNumber
```

It nicely formats all kinds of stuff ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0',5-LEN('9'))+'9'
```

The result is string

Comment: Something more like this would work better:

`SELECT REPLICATE('0',5-LEN(CAST(number AS NVARCHAR))) + CAST(number AS NVARCHAR)`